# Send UDP package (lwip, Cortex M3, Stellaris LM3S6965 Evaluation Board)

Tags: c, udp, cortex-m, lwip

I'm working with Cortex M3, Stellaris® LM3S6965 Evaluation Board. I'm trying to send an UDP packet to an NTP server. I have been searching for days and days.

But its not working. Can someone help me? I think the callback function is not getting called.

```
int main(void){
   sendUDP();
}

void sendUDP(void){

    //UDP

    struct ip_addr dstaddr;
    struct ip_addr srcaddr;
    struct udp_pcb * pcb;
    u16_t * dst_port;
    struct pbuf * pb;

    char str[512]="Test Sander";
    IP4_ADDR(&dstaddr,65,55,21,24); // time.windows.com
    IP4_ADDR(&srcaddr,192,168,1,10); // cortex
    dst_port = 123;

    pcb = udp_new();

    RIT128x96x4Enable(1000000);
    RIT128x96x4StringDraw("UDP CONNECT", 45, 45, 15);

    udp_bind(pcb,&srcaddr,&dst_port);
    udp_connect(pcb,&dstaddr,&dst_port);

    pb = pbuf_alloc(PBUF_TRANSPORT, 512, PBUF_REF);
    pb->payload = str;
    pb->len = pb->tot_len = 512;

    udp_sendto(pcb, &pb,&dstaddr,dst_port);
    //udp_send(pcb, &pb);

    udp_recv(pcb, RecvUTPCallBack, NULL);

    pbuf_free(pb);

    udp_remove(pcb);


}

// Function gets called when we recieve data
err_t RecvUTPCallBack(void *arg, struct udp_pcb *upcb, struct pbuf *p, struct ip_addr *addr, u16_t port){
    RIT128x96x4Enable(1000000);
    RIT128x96x4StringDraw("ENTERING CALLBACK", 40, 40, 11);


    volatile int totaal_lengte=0;
    totaal_lengte = p->tot_len;
    volatile int line=40;

    while(1){

        RIT128x96x4Enable(1000000);
        RIT128x96x4StringDraw(p->payload+1, 0, line, 15);
        line+=8;
        if(p->len != p->tot_len){
            p=p->next;
        }
        else break;
    }
    pbuf_free(p);
}
```

Full code of program: http://codepaste.net/uuy8sg

Comment: Did you try the NTP code from LwIP Contrib page --> http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/lwip/lwip-contrib.git/tree/apps/sntp

Answer (score 1):

I think you're having a race condition.

You're registering the callback, but immediately after sending out the packet, you exit your `sendUDP()` function, which in turn causes `main()` to end.

You need to provide some time, it might be hundreds of milliseconds before the response comes in, and you never wait for it to happen.

I'm not familiar with eCosPro which seems to be the operating system you're using, but there should be some "sleep" call that just lets your program idle and gives the system a chance to listen for a response and trigger the callback.

Also, I think you need to call more i[nitialization functions](http://www.ecoscentric.com/ecospro/doc/html/ref/lwip-api-raw-init.html), like `udp_init()` to set up the UDP support.

Comment: I have added a forloop, i know its not clean but now that gives it some time. 

`for(idelay = 0; idelay < 3000000; idelay++);` 

This code is after udp_sendto(); and before udp_recv();  Same result

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a super old question but ...

`dst_port` should not be a pointer.

```
//u16_t * dst_port;
u16_t dst_port;
dst_port = 123;
```

This is probably the line that causes the problem:

```
udp_bind(pcb,&srcaddr,&dst_port);
```

It should be

```
udp_bind(pcb,&srcaddr, dst_port);
```

Answer (score -1):

change from:

```
udp_bind(pcb,&srcaddr,&dst_port);
udp_connect(pcb,&dstaddr,&dst_port);
```

to:

```
udp_bind(pcb,&srcaddr,dst_port);
//udp_connect(pcb,&dstaddr,dst_port);
```